# Importing numbers from a grid into a 2D Array Java

Tags: java, arrays

So just a quick question here, I have done some work with file reading but not enough to be proficient with it. I have a grid:

```
10 14 81 34 76

18 22 64 4  87

1  6  42 13 15

4  32 21 87 31

7  42 24 20 15
```

(just an example grid)

I have it in a text file currently. How do I input each number into its own place on a 2D array, seems simple but with my limited knowledge I have been unable to do it!

Comment: Can you show us what you got so far and ask specifically, what does not work in your attempt?

Comment: I am just not exactly sure how to go about it, I know how to do basic input from files and write to them, but I have only done delineation once.

Comment: 1. Read each line of the file into an ArrayList.
  
2. Write a function that takes a String and returns an ArrayList of Integers by splitting the String on whitespace and converting each element into an Integer.
  
3. Use your function to put each line into an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

Answer (score 1):

Assume first you know the size. first step is to do file reading. create a bufferreader

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```

Then loop through this reader

```
int[][] result=new int[rownum][columnnum];
int i =0;
While(br.ready()){
    String line=br.readline();
    String[] tokens=line.split(" ");
    // now put each in 2D array
   for(int j=0;j<tokens.length;j++){
        result[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
    }
    i ++;
}
```

If you don't know the size then in that loop you put in ArrayList. Then use toArray method

Comment: I am getting an error with the String line = br.readline(); saying the method readline() is undefined for the type buffered reader.

Comment: When I do that I get: Unhandled Exception type IOException

Comment: Nvm, throws IOException after start of main method fixed that, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Well , Its pretty logical .

Let's breakdown your grid ,

1. It is space delimited
2. Consider each line to be a row of a 2D array.

Here's some code ,

```
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    fileReader.close();
```

Now the ArrayList lines has all your lines from the textfile. All you have to do now , is iterate throught it with a simple for loop and extract the values.

```
String [] singleline = lines.get(0).split(" "); // this array contains all integers at line 0 .
```

just parse it to an integer value and add it to your 2D array in any way you prefer .

```
 ArrayList<Integer> singleLineIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
 singleLineIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
```

Now this singleLineIntegers array Contains all the integers in line 1 , use the lines array to repeat this and insert it into your 2d array.